# How to run library with composer?

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer-php

I'm trying to install [this github repo](https://github.com/blockchain/api-v1-client-php) to my project (running on codeigniter). The steps I'm doing is very simple:

```
    {
      "name": "project",
      "description": "",
      "license": "MIT",
      "require": {
          "php" : ">=5.3.0",
          "blockchain/blockchain" : "1.*",
          "ext-curl": "*"
      },
  "require-dev": {

  }
} // composer.json
```

and run `php composer.phar update`. So the package installs but I can't use it in my project - I don't think its autoloaded. `/vendor/autoload.php` is required in my index.php. When I try it with different package for test purposes (kriswallsmith/buzz) - it works. So what I'm doing wrong?

Also I checked my `vendor/composer/installed.json` and I see this:

```
    [
    {
        "name": "blockchain/blockchain",
        "version": "v1.0",
        "version_normalized": "1.0.0.0",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/blockchain/api-v1-client-php.git",
            "reference": "c219b9b00778cf6c025628bd34fd6543922fe81b"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/blockchain/api-v1-client-php/zipball/c219b9b00778cf6c025628bd34fd6543$
            "reference": "c219b9b00778cf6c025628bd34fd6543922fe81b",
            "shasum": ""
        },
        "require": {
            "ext-curl": "*",
            "php": ">=5.3.0"
        },
        "time": "2015-02-03 18:34:11",
        "type": "library",
        "installation-source": "dist",
        "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
                "Blockchain\\": "src/"
            }
        },
        "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
        "license": [
            "MIT"
        ],
        "description": "Blockchain API client library",
        "homepage": "https://github.com/blockchain/api-v1-client-php",
        "keywords": [
            "bitcoin",
            "blockchain"
        ]
    }
]
```

and my function where I'm trying to use this lib:

```
private function __check_btc_balance()
{
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $Blockchain = new \Blockchain\Blockchain(PAYMENTS_BTC_API_CODE);
}
```

Comment: Where you put your vendor folder!!

Comment: Used `composer dump-autoload` and still nothing. My `vendor` is in my project root.

Comment: as I said in the question - its working with another library. So the path is working correcty

Comment: can you write some code from the part where you are trying to use the library?

Comment: @gmponos edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you followed the installation steps?

Basically there are some differences from common composer packages. Over here it says **download** the source code and run `composer install` from it's **own** folder

Then **include the autoloader file** from the folder of the downloaded files so you will have somewhere a folder `Blockchain/vendor/autoload.php` to include

> Download the source or clone the repository. This php library works
>   with the Composer package manager. Navigate to the root of the
>   repository and run
>
> $ composer install
>
> This will create the /vendor folder in the repository root. In the php
>   source, simply:
>
> // Include the autoload.php from its vendor directory require
>   'vendor/autoload.php'
>
> // Create the base Blockchain class instance

Comment: yes, this was the problem, I installed this lib via composer, not downloaded. So it was older version, with the bugs..

Answer (score 0):

I've seen ...

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Blockchain\\": "src/"
        }
    },
```

I always keep all my code in src\Vendor\Project\Filename.php and composer autoloader works with this. Try to add this lines of code:

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "": "src/"
        }
    },
```

Comment: still nothing. Also in my `autoload_psr4.php` is written: `return array(
    'Blockchain\\' => array($vendorDir . '/blockchain/blockchain/src'),
);`

Comment: Oh now I see the error: `Class 'Blockchain\PushTX\Push' not found in <b>/var/www/html/vendor/blockchain/blockchain
/src/Blockchain.php</b>`